# Is there a way to paginate html pages that look like slides in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have this API that converts pptx files to html, and returns the files in html form which I then display on my site. Is there a way to paginate the html using React or plain JavaScript such that I can load each slide individually? Or a way of loading each slide of the html based on something like a separator?

Comment: If you don't mind using a library, look into [fullPage](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/).

Comment: Awesome, @eMontielG let me look into that

Comment: @eMontielG looking into how it works, it seems to me that `fullPage` is a solution if you want to display the slide after breaking down the html into sections(pagination or something)..pagination is the problem i'm seeking to solve i.e how to display each single slide individually

Comment: @AllanMogusu can you share a snippet of an API response ?
I don't think there is a straight forward solution for you scenario and the API response is key for understanding how to split it to pages.

Comment: The API returns a html page which I then provide via a CDN..I actually load the html page from the CDN...the page looks very much like a powerpoint slide but is html? I think you understand how powerpoint slides look...my problem is how to paginate that html into independent slides and display each slide on my frontend

Comment: By html page you mean a whole new document? With `<head>` tags and their own `<body>`?

Comment: Sure @eMontielG

Comment: You can store them in iframes and use those as slides for fullPage.